# Does INT_MIN % -1 produce undefined behavior?

Tags: c, gcc, overflow, division, modulo

gcc generates floating code that raises `SIGFPE` for the following code:

```
#include <limits.h>
int x = -1;
int main()
{
    return INT_MIN % x;
}
```

However I can find no statement in the standard that this code invokes undefined or implementation-defined behavior. As far as I can tell, it's required to return 0. Is this a bug in gcc or am I missing some special exception the standard makes?

Comment: Note that the global variable is to prevent gcc from optimizing out the computation.

Comment: What would you expect as a result trying to getting the modulo of a negative number?

Comment: "When either a or n are negative, this naive definition breaks down and programming languages differ in how these values are defined". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: I would expect the remainder of `INT_MIN` divided by `-1`, which, regardless of whether you define your remainder to be positive or negative in this case, is zero, since `-1` divides anything evenly.

Comment: C defines them in this case, and in any case, when the denominator is 1 or -1, there is no ambiguity of definition because the remainder is inherently zero.

Comment: @R..: does this apply only for the INT_MIN macro?

Comment: @gio: It also applies to `LONG_MIN` etc. or the equivalent values obtained from any source other than the macro. Use of the macro name is just a convenient way to express the question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are probably right that this can be considered as a bug in the actual standard. The [current draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf) addresses this problem:

> If the quotient a/b is representable,
>   the expression (a/b)*b + a%b shall
>   equal a; otherwise, the behavior of
>   both a/b and a%b is undefined.

Comment: Accepted; this answer addresses the bug and the fix adopted by the committee. Sorry it took so long.

Comment: Is this language likely to be included in a TC to C99?

Comment: @caf, my guess would be that there will be no TC to C99, because C1x is intended to replace it.

Answer (score 16):

Looking at the assembly code generated by gcc (x is defined as -1 earlier in the assembly):

```
movl    x, %ecx
movl    $-2147483648, %eax
movl    %eax, %edx
sarl    $31, %edx
idivl   %ecx
```

The first computational instruction, `sarl`, right shifts `-2147483648` 31 bits. This results in `-1` which is put in `%edx`.

Next `idivl` is executed. This is a signed operation. Let me quote the description:

> Divides the contents of the double-word contained in the combined %edx:%eax registers by the value in the register or memory location specified.

So `-1:-2147483648 / -1` is the division that happens. `-1:-2147483648` interpreted as a double word equals `-2147483648` (on a two's complement machine). Now `-2147483648 / -1` happens which returns `2147483648`. BOOM! That's one more then `INT_MAX`.

---

About the why question, is this a bug in gcc or am I missing some special exception the standard makes?

In the C99 standard this is implicit UB (§6.5.5/6):

> …the result of the / operator is the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded.88) If the quotient a/b is representable, the expression (a/b)*b + a%b shall equal a.

`INT_MIN / -1` cannot be represented, thus this is UB.

In C89 however the % operator is implementation defined and whether this is a compiler bug or not can be debated. The issue is listed at gcc however: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=30484

Comment: Your information about *how* the `SIGFPE` is happening is correct. My concern though is whether this is correct. I never asked the compiler to compute `INT_MIN/-1` (which would clearly result in UB since it overflows), just to compute `INT_MIN%-1`, and I can find no statement in the standard that the latter invokes UB. Still, an informative answer.

Comment: Regarding your citation of 6.5.5/6: in the previous paragraph (5), it reads "the result of the % operator is the remainder". Paragraph 6 clarifies that when "the remainder" could be ambiguous, but "the remainder" is not ambiguous when `a` is a whole multiple of `b`; in this case the unique remainder is 0.

Comment: @R.: Hmm, wait a sec, the standard states "If the quotient a/b is representable", which is not the case in INT_MIN % -1. It doesn't state what should happen when this happens, thus it's UB.

Comment: It already stated in paragraph 5 that the result of `%` is "the remainder". As written, paragraph 6 merely clarifies which "the remainder" it's talking about. I think you may be right that the *intent* was not to define any behavior for `INT_MAX%-1`, but I don't see how the present language would accomplish that since it already defined it above...

Comment: The standard says "if the quotient a/b is representable in the type of the result, (a/b)*b + a%b is equal to a." This statement does not restrict the behavior in situations when the quotient is *not* representable, which means that the previous statements remain in effect. The previous statements state that `%` produces the remainder. And the remainder in this case is 0.

Answer (score 9):

[It's the CPU's fault](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=30484).

Comment: Thanks for the informative link. At least it looks like people are mostly in agreement that it's a bug, but the "leave it broken by default and require a special option to fix it" approach sounds ridiculous...

Comment: Is there any simple bitwise/arithmetic expression that evaluates to `x` if `x!=-1` and `1` if `x==1`? If so, the compiler could apply this to the denominator before performing `%` with a variable denominator when `/` is not also being performed with the same denominator.

Comment: @R..: "off by default but on in standard-conforming modes" sounds alright, though, and that's what's suggested on the bug. `gcc` is not a conforming implementation, nor does it claim to be. `gcc -std=c99` isn't entirely conforming either, but it does attempt to be...

Answer (score 4):

The same question is asked here as a Defect Report

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#614

Unfortunately I don't see it stated explicitly in the resolution part that it should produce UB. The division would indeed produce UB, but for the `%` operator it is not obvious.

Answer (score 3):

The result of the modulus operation with negative operands is left implementation-defined in C89, and defined in C99 by §6.5.5/6:

> …the result of the `/` operator is the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded.<sup>88)</sup> If the quotient `a/b` is representable, the expression `(a/b)*b` + `a%b` shall equal `a`.
>
> <sup>88)</sup> This is often called "truncation toward zero".

For a two's-complement representation, `INT_MIN / -1` is equal to `INT_MAX + 1`, so it's not representable as an `int` without wrapping, and I guess the implementation elects to leave it explosive.

Comment: The `/` operator does not appear in my program, however. And regardless of how you define the result with negative operands ("rounding" towards 0 or down), -1 evenly divides anything and thus the only possible remainder is zero, mathematically.

Comment: @R..: I was just citing a reference for the behaviour with respect to negative operands. The computation fails as GCC implements it, so it's basically a bug, if you need me to say it in so many words.

Comment: @R..: To put it another way, `%` is defined only when `/` is defined, and since `/` is here undefined, `%` is also undefined, even though it probably shouldn't be.